# Intellij Run pops up When I Debug

Tags: intellij-idea

I think I dragged the "Debug-Run" tab out and now it shows up as a separate window whenever I debug. How do I revert it so it doesn't pop up as a separate window? The regular run doesn't float though.

[image]

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have dragged the Console tab out into its own window - out of the Debug window.

Click and hold the console tab on that window and drop it back into the Debug window

[image: DragAndDrop]

Comment: Thanks! It's not really an obvious solution to me because I'm not super used to Intellij. It was also super annoying cause the console always popped up in front of the variables.